# Replacing the Print Command in a python script with a comment

Tags: python, string, replace

I have the command below in a .py file

```
print(r"\n print series")
```

I want the above command/line to be replaced with a string:

"#series" ie convert the above print command into a comment prefixing the # symbol to the text following the "print" in the command above.

I am new to python. Please help.

This question was closed earlier as it was not clear what I was attempting to do. Hence, the explanation that follows:

The reason for doing this: I want to use print statements in a script for learning python/using as reference. Later, I want to change the print statement into a comment. Hence, I want to replace the beginning of the print statement with a # which will convert it into a comment. As there would be many such conversions, I wanted to do it programmatically using a string.replace or something else. Any suggestions to achieve this in another way are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. `str.replace` is a good approach.

Comment: If the goal is to just disable `print` calls, you can do that [with one of the solutions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/how-to-block-calls-to-print). If you want to use comments and run it across a set of files, [sed would be easier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file). If you want to do it in Python, the [inspect module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231131/annotating-python-print-output-with-comments) would be useful (this example isn't exactly what you're looking for, but close).

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I intended to convert the print command into a string using this line
s1 =  str(print(r"\n print series")) and then slicing that string and concatenating with # to achieve what I wanted. Unfortunately, s1 is getting assigned the value "None". Hence, unable to do what I want.

Comment: `print` always returns `None`. Slicing and such isn't necessary when using the `replace` method.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I tried this to replace the string before slicing:
 s1.replace("print(r"\n print", "#") but it returns this error:SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (pointing at the \n in string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this within your script itself (as opposed to doing a find+replace on the code), what I'd suggest would be wrapping the `print` calls in a function that you can switch off:

```
DEBUG = True

def debug_print(*args, **kwargs):
    if DEBUG:
        print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then if you have a bunch of calls like:

```
debug_print(r"\n print series")
```

they will only print as long as `DEBUG` is `True`.  When you want to turn off all those print statements, you can just edit that one line:

```
DEBUG = False
```

and now nothing prints.

Comment: Thanks, Tried this. Meets my needs. Effectively, the comments are inside the debug_print statement and can be printed in the output or read from within the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using regex

1. Store the command as a string in a variable called 'command'.
2. Substitute the 'print' keyword with a '#' symbol and remove the '\n' character using regex. Making sure to use '.strip()' to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

```
import re
command = r"\n print series"
comment = re.sub(r"\bprint\b\s*", "#", command.replace(r"\n", "")).strip()
print(comment)
```

This should output `#series`, hope this helps.