# Multiline f-string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.6, f-string

I'm trying to write PEP-8 compliant code for a domestic project and I have a line with an f-string that is more than 80 characters long:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.data} - {self.time},\nTags: {self.tags},\nText: {self.text}'
```

I'm trying to split it into different lines in the most *Pythonic* way but the only answer that actually works is an error for my linter.

Working code:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.date} - {self.time},\nTags:' + \
    f' {self.tags},\nText: {self.text}'
```

Output:

```
2017-08-30 - 17:58:08.307055,
Tags: test tag,
Text: test text
```

The linter thinks that I'm not respecting [E122](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E122.html) from [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), is there a way to get the string right and the code compliant?

Comment: You dont have to return it all on one line, create a base string in a variable then append each part using `+=`. Then just return the variable. The reason it doesnt comply with E122 is possibly because you aren't indenting the following line.

Comment: What's the full description of E122?

Comment: or just tell your ide to increase the line character limit, or ignore that rule all together

Comment: @JoshLee "E122 continuation line missing indentation or outdented main"
also why you closed the question? There are no duplicates, its the only one about multiline f-strings

Comment: for the others, this isnt a question about the code, is a question about how to makes multilines f-string looks good and pep-8 compliant without cheesy hacks and non-pythonic styles

Comment: @Owlzy Isn't the answer the exact same: use parenthesis, not the line-continuation marker?

Comment: Also, please clarify if you are talking about a string with linebreaks in it (`\n`) or a multi-line string **literal** (which you don't have, you just added a couple single-line f-string literals).

Answer (score 377, accepted):

From [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces.

Given this, the following would solve your problem in a PEP-8 compliant way.

```
return (
    f'{self.date} - {self.time}\n'
    f'Tags: {self.tags}\n'
    f'Text: {self.text}'
)
```

Python strings will automatically concatenate when not separated by a comma, so you do not need to explicitly call `join()`.

Comment: Wouldn't the `\n` cause problems in Windows? Is there a way to do this without the Unix-specific `\n`?

Comment: No problems on Windows. The `\n` is platform agnostic as Python has had [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) enabled by default since 3.0.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried this and it worked. Forgot to update here. Good old Python :').

Comment: Keep in mind that this is probably less efficient than doing one big f-string, because of extra intermediate (de-)allocations and copying. But it is a good tradeoff for more readable code!

Comment: The `\n` only works if you use `print(...)`, but not, when using return (...). Then `\n` is shown in the output, it is not understood as newline. No need to say, it is still working if you just print the return value. Another idea is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090379/11154841),

Comment: What's the recommended style if only some lines contain variables? Should `f` only be added to the lines that have variables or should it be on every line for consistency?

Comment: In my case, the expression inside `{..}` is too long and needs to be broken over many lines. How to do that?

Comment: @MattiasWallin This generates the exact same bytecode as one big f-string would.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Correct! Tested in Compiler explorer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174539/python-string-literal-concatenation) suggests it is concatenated during parsing. [Reference manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) says it is equivalent to concatenated version.

Comment: @MattiasWallin @MateenUlhaq According to [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#concatenating-strings), formatted string literals are concatenated at runtime. So, are implicit string concatenations equivalent to explicit ones? `(f"Line {x}" f"Line {y}")` is the same as `f"Line {x}" + f"Line {y}"` at runtime? If that's true, one big f-string would be slightly faster.

Comment: @SaberHayati The [generated bytecode](https://godbolt.org/z/qxMdzK3d5) is the same for `f"x={x}" f"y={y}"` and `f"x={x} y={y}"` (builds one string, 7 ops). But not the same for `f"x={x}" + f" y={y}` (builds two strings and then adds them, 9 ops).

Answer (score 90):

I think it would be

```
return f'''{self.date} - {self.time},
Tags: {self.tags},
Text: {self.text}'''
```

Comment: now that its closed i can delete this answer if people think i should ... but its not covered in the dupe answer :/\

Comment: but this kind of multiline defeats the purpose of f-strings and indentation

Also I dont feel like this is the right use of the triple quote strings, feels like an hack

Comment: While this answer does replicate the OP's intent, I feel like @noddy's answer is better.  This answer *just happens* to be correct because the OP also wanted multi-line in the output.  If you wanted the output to have a different layout than the source code, triple quotes are not the way to go.

Comment: Looks nice, but creates problems with indentation and code layout.

Comment: mix this with the builtin `inspect.cleandoc` function and you'll have  a good day :)

Comment: Yeah, I prefer this solution combined with `inspect.cleandoc` as well.

Comment: @Owlzy can you explain what you mean how "this kind of multiline defeats the purpose of f-strings and indentation"? And I'm adding a link for @Zack Plauche's reference to [`inspect.cleandoc`](https://github.com/jmurty/til/blob/main/python/use-multi-line-text-blocks-with-inspect-cleandoc.md) which "cleans up" leading indentations/spaces

Comment: @NateAnderson my answer is more than 5 years old but the answer to your message was given by Mike Williamson 3 years ago in the comment directly under mine. Potentially I didn't need to have the output text on multiple lines, rendering this solution useless and off topic

Comment: OK @Owlzy, I like Mike's comment; I can see why  [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950733/1175496) is better than this answer, esp considering [PEP-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874592/how-to-write-very-long-string-that-conforms-with-pep8-and-prevent-e501); if your OP didn't ask about a string **with linebreaks**, then a **multiline** aka "triple-quote" string (seen in this answer) wouldn't help? I'm not sure this (or [other highly-voted answers suggesting multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090379/1175496)) is "useless and off topic" as you say....

Comment: Maybe a multiline string "feels like an hack" because multiline are often used as Python [docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings), instead of string values stored in variables?? Anyway I'm glad to learn **f-strings and multiline strings can work together**, *and* that parentheses are "the preferred way of wrapping long lines". I wonder which is the [most performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965007/multiline-f-string-in-python/45965132?noredirect=1#comment124116413_54950733) (maybe premature optimization). I'm glad I found this Q&A, even 5 years late.

Answer (score 83):

You can use either triple single quotation marks or triple double quotation marks, but put an f at the beginning of the string:

#### Triple Single Quotes

```py
return f'''{self.date} - {self.time},
Tags:' {self.tags},
Text: {self.text}'''
```

#### Triple Double Quotes

```
return f"""{self.date} - {self.time},
Tags:' {self.tags},
Text: {self.text}"""
```

**Notice that you don't need to use "\n" because you are using a multiple-line string.**

Comment: Good point about "\n" - and here is [another reference](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/) that also explains it's not necessary for multiline Strings (in section, "Multiline Strings with Triple Quotes").

Comment: To avoid braking, curly brackets {} can be escaped by doing {{}}.

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned by @noddy, the approach also works for variable assignment expression:

```python
var1 = "foo"
var2 = "bar"
concat_var = (f"First var is: {var1}"
              f" and in same line Second var is: {var2}")
print(concat_var)
```

should give you:

```
First var is: foo and in same line Second var is: bar
```

Answer (score 11):

You can mix the multiline quoting styles and regular strings and f-strings:

```
foo = 'bar'
baz = 'bletch'
print(f'foo is {foo}!\n',
      'bar is bar!\n',
      f"baz is {baz}!\n",
      "not f-string version: baz is {baz}!\n",
      '''bletch
      is
      bletch!''')
```

Prints this (note the indentation):

```
foo is bar!
 bar is bar!
 baz is bletch!
 not f-string version: baz is {baz}!
 bletch
      is
      bletch!
```