# Any way to capture the entirety of the terminal?

Tags: python

I am using `discord.py` and I need the bot to send a multi-line message.  This is easy to do, but sending each line separately is a pain and it isn't very quick.  So I thought, why not have it send the whole shebang at once?

All I need is to somehow take everything inside of the terminal and set that as a variable that I can later send as a single message.

Here's the entire terminal output:

[image: Here's the entire terminal output]

Comment: Can't you just send a message that has linebreaks inside it?

Comment: i dont see how i could.  the data that is printed comes from a cycled list where the number of items is inconsistant.

Comment: @Samwise you were right man, i just had to use the range of the len(list)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is roughly tabular - why not write to csv or json and send it that way?

Alternatively, f-strings in python preserve formatting, and can be multiple lines, although I don't think that's recommended by PEP8.

**EDIT** Here is a somewhat related question that covers multi-line strings: [Multiline f-string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965007/multiline-f-string-in-python)