# Use environmental variables in between strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, environment-variables, string-formatting

I have a string

```
start = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope \
         xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                    <UserName>username</UserName><Password>password</Password>\
                    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><oShipData>"""
```

I want to use environmental variables for username and password, instead of hardcoding them in the code, I tried this

```
import os
start = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope \
         xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                    <UserName>"""os.environ["username"]"""</UserName><Password>"""os.environ["password"]"""</Password>
                    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><oShipData>"""
```

But this gives me an error:

```
"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'test': invalid syntax (test.py, line 5)",
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError"
```

How can I escape the strings and dynamically get values from `os.environ` within the strings?

Comment: Just add `+` on both sides to let it work. There're plenty of methods how you can achieve required result, take a look on [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Your data is in XML format, so it'll be good to use [`xml.etree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to build XML object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline f-string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965007/multiline-f-string-in-python)

Comment: @RandomDavis , I tried using similar formatting like this f"house_bill_nbr = '{house_bill_nbr}'" in my code, but since this is XML, it was not accepting that kind of formatting

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't just put the string and the code next to another, you muse concatenate them with a `+`

```
start = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
        <UserName>""" + os.environ["username"] + """</UserName>
        <Password>""" + os.environ["password"] + """</Password>
    <oShipData>"""
```

Comment: You leave empty first line

Comment: To avoid empty first line, add a backslash to the end of the `start = """` line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use f-strings:

```
import os
start = f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope \
         xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                    <UserName>{os.environ['username']}</UserName><Password>{os.environ['password']}</Password>
                    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><oShipData>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add strings together in python. So `"teststring"` is a normal string, but `"test"+variable+"string"` will result in a string that has the value of variable in the middle, assuming that variable is of type string. If not, use `"test"+str(variable)+"string"`.

```
import os
start = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope \
         xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
                    <UserName>"""+str(os.environ["username"])+"""</UserName><Password>"""+str(os.environ["password"])+"""</Password>
                    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><oShipData>"""
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to work with XML object, it's always good to use some classes which generate XML document. In python there's built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**Code:**

```py
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

envelope = ET.Element("soap:Envelope", attrib={"xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"})
username = ET.SubElement(envelope, "UserName")
username.text = os.environ["username"]
password = ET.SubElement(envelope, "Password")
password.text = os.environ["password"]

start = ET.tostring(envelope, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True).decode()
```

**Result:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><UserName>user</UserName><Password>pass</Password></soap:Envelope>
```

P.S. On python 3.9+ you can use [`ET.indent(envelope)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) to get pretty printed result *(insert this before `ET.tostring()` call)*.