# Indentation appears in the output string when broken it over multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I have large `f-string`, and I am braking it (see below), for code readability.
but when I print (print to file, it is `String.IO` object) the string I get the indentation leading each new line (except the first), and I don't want that (my IDE is `vscode`).
When taking the same `f-string` below, to the python shell interpreter (`REPL`), the output string is proper.

```
def foo():
    ml.append(f"""
    #define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_MASK (MASK({H},{L}))
    #define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_START_BIT ({fieldsb})\n""")
```

the output file looks like:

```
#define QM_MEM_CBTIRDY_LENGTH (0x40)                           //good line
        #define QM_MEM_CBTIRDY_DATA_MASK (GENMASK(31,0))       //bad line (with indentation)
        #define QM_MEM_CBTIRDY_DATA_START_BIT (0)
```

I have fix it by removing the indentation between each new line (but its ugly cos the strings with the same function def indentation level, and this is ugly)

```
def foo():
    ml.append(f"""
#define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_MASK (MASK({H},{L}))
define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_START_BIT ({fieldsb})\n""")
```

how can i get rid of these indentation characters in the final string ?

Answer (score 1):

Triple-quoted (multiline) strings are supposed to preserve the formatting, so that's why you're getting those identations.

You can use concatenation instead:

```
ml.append(f"#define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_MASK (MASK({H},{L}))\n"
          f"#define {ip}_{mtype}_{secname}_{fieldname}_START_BIT ({fieldsb})\n")
```

or if you still prefer multi-line strings, you can [trim them in a similar way to docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id18).

Comment: I don't think we need the + operation here. Python will concatenate strings without the use of +. A related answer can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950733/3766568).

Comment: @Safwan, you're correct. I've updated the answer.