# Assigning two string objects to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I understand that the below code results in `SyntaxError`:

```
x = 1 2
print(x)
```

But, I am not able to understand why below code is not throwing same synatax error:

```
x = "DataScience" "4U"
print(x)     #DataScience4U
```

Comment: When the Python parser encounters consecutive string literals, it treats them as one concatenated string. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174539/python-string-literal-concatenation